# Light switches behaving strangely

Tags: electrical, lighting

I’ve recently had a small integral garage conversion and 1 pendant light and 1 spot light were put in the 2 new rooms. Prior to this there were two pendant lights in the garage. We had an extra light switch put in so the two lights were controlled from one switch in the past, but now have their own wall switches. The lights were all on the same circuit as the rest of the downstairs lights.

I also had some roofing work done which I suspect didn’t cause any internal issues as it was just cleaning and fixing tiles. I’ve mentioned it in case it is relevant to an expert.

My front room has 11 lights wired to the circuit (not a big room but they are wall lights). Hall has one light, kitchen 4 spots, new toilet 1 spot and new room 1 pendant. Total 17 lights on one circuit… now my downstairs front room (with 11 lights) wall switch doesn’t work. No lights come on. If I turn the hall light off then the front room switches (one or two of them) turn on the hall light or make it flicker.

Is my circuit overloaded or is it more likely something was damaged in the loft with the roof work? Or is it something else? We have only started seeing the problem today annoyingly the day after the roof work but also the day after we started using the light in the new room all evening for cleaning and decorating… so I can’t know which thing caused it.

Any expert advice?

Comment: I doubt you have an overload, particularly if you have not had any breakers trip. But the way to figure out whether you have too many lights is to add up the rating (usually in Watts) and see how that compares to your circuit. For example, a 15A 120V circuit should only be loaded to 80% = 15 x 120 x .8 = 1,440 W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> now my downstairs front room (with 11 lights) wall switch doesn’t work. No lights come on. If I turn the hall light off then the front room switches (one or two of them) turn on the hall light or make it flicker.

It sounds like you have a 3way switch in the hall and front room that may have some loose wiring.

If the circuit was overloaded the breaker to that circuit would open.

Have the electrician that did the work come back to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Your advice is very much appreciated